# basic php classes, error catching for arguments

Tags: php, class

I have a pretty basic question on whether or not what I'm doing is a good practice, or is overkill.

```
class myClass
{
    public function doSomething($thing=false)
    {
        if (!$thing) echo "Your thing is missing!";
        echo "Did you get that $thing I sentcha?";
    }
}
```

Should every function have these precautions, or only those that could be likely to be mis-used (though, I suppose finding those functions is subjective).

Is it a good practice to set function arguments to false (assuming they should normally carry non-falsy values)? This also prevents other developers from mis-using the functions, mainly if they forget to enter a value.

Or ... Is this a waste/overkill if I assume developers using this function will use it correctly and not leave out `$thing`?

Comment: The best idea is to not give a default value for your parameters if they're required. Just omit `=false` and PHP will take care of it for you. (Also, `null` is a better choice for a 'not set' value than `false`.)

Comment: Use exceptions for this

Comment: thanks @WaleedKhan - I guess I'm trying to avoid those `Warning:  Missing argument` errors. So you think it'd be better to just check `if (!isset($arg))` and leave off the default value?

Comment: @d-_-b There is only one way that you ought to avoid those errors: by never having any place in your code where you call a function without all its arguments. PHP's loud complaints are to be heeded and not ignored.

Answer (score 4):

don't do that, a function with a pre-set parameter value is basically an invitation to NOT pass an argument. Especially if you're using an IDE with auto-complete...

PHP will complain if the method is called with a missing parameter, and you should actively check if the parameter is valid and if this is not the case, throw an exception.

As a general rule, try to extend your validation so that the actual format (number, string, percentage, currency, ....) is validated instead of just checking if "something" is there ;)